# Mysql code does not accept select statements that work fine alone but in union fail

Tags: mysql

I have the following code. The selects within the join work great by themselves, but when I try to get it to work in the join, I get an error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as S) on tup.userid=user_id' at line 1

```
Select tup.*, tu.email, S.user_id, S.name, S.value
From tb_user_profile tup
join tb_user tu on tup.userid=tu.id
Join((Select tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance 
      from tb_bank_account tba )as T  
      union  
      Select tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value     
      from tb_property_item tpi )as S) on tup.userid=user_id
```

What am I doing wrong? Second, I need to add two other tables to the above structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't alias the subqueries in a `union`; you put the alias at the very end.  Try this:

```
Select tup.*, tu.email, S.user_id, S.name, S.value
From tb_user_profile tup join
     tb_user tu
     on tup.userid = tu.id Join
     ((Select tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance 
       from tb_bank_account tba
      ) union  
      (Select tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value     
       from tb_property_item tpi
      )
     ) s
     on tup.userid = s.user_id ;
```

By the way, `union all` is more efficient than `union`, if you know you do not have or do not care about duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Don't alias the selects of a `union`

```
Select tup.*, tu.email, X.user_id, X.name, X.value
From tb_user_profile tup
join tb_user tu on tup.userid=tu.id
Join
(
    Select tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance 
    from tb_bank_account tba
    union  
    Select tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value     
    from tb_property_item tpi
) X on tup.userid = Xuser_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your query, and I found this:

1. Errors in your parenthesis: You open some and forget to close them
2. You declared an alias twice
3. You forgot to write the rowsource in your last `on` clause.

I recommend you write your queries in a way that is easy to review. Here is the correction:

```
select 
    tup.*, tu.email, S.user_id, S.name, S.value
from 
    tb_user_profile tup
    join tb_user tu on tup.userid=tu.id
    join (
        select 
            tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance 
        from 
            tb_bank_account as tba
        union select 
            tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value     
        from 
            tb_property_item as tpi 
    ) as S on tup.userid=s.user_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your UNION'ed statements must have the same exact number of columns, and those column types must be identical in their order.  The columns may be different sources, just be sure the count and types are in the same order.  Returned column names and types are determined by the first SELECT.

You are SELECTing * plus 5 more columns in the first select.  Your secondary select only has 2 columns.

Edit:  Your code cleanup changes my answer:
Your subquery table is not aliased, SQL does not know how to refer to it.  Also the ON is ambiguous.  Which userid??  Try changing to this:

```
Select tup.*, tu.email, S.user_id, S.name, S.value
From tb_user_profile tup
join tb_user tu on tup.userid=tu.id
Join (Select tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance 
      from tb_bank_account tba
      union  
      Select tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value     
      from tb_property_item tpi) S on tup.userid=S.id
```

Comment: The number of columns for the union are identical. It's 3 columns in the first part: `tba.id, tba.accountName, tba.currentBalance` and 3 columns in the second: `tpi.user_id, tpi.name, tpi.value`

Comment: If I remove the union with the Select underit the code works. If I remove the Select right after the join upto just after the union that code will work. But I combine the two they do not like each other and the code errors. The two selects that error have the same output structure.